# Prevent unwanted query string in datatables

Tags: datatable

I am using datatables with server side processing. It sends all parameters to the server for even a basic operation like column sorting. How to prevent it, any idea? Here is the ajax get parameters that are passed as query string.

```
columns[0][data]    0
columns[0][name]    
columns[0][orderable]   true
columns[0][search][regex]   false
columns[0][search][value]   
columns[0][searchable]  true
columns[1][data]    1
columns[1][name]    
columns[1][orderable]   true
columns[1][search][regex]   false
columns[1][search][value]   
columns[1][searchable]  true
columns[2][data]    2
columns[2][name]    
columns[2][orderable]   true
columns[2][search][regex]   false
columns[2][search][value]   
columns[2][searchable]  true
draw    2
length  10
order[0][column]    1
order[0][dir]   asc
search[regex]   false
search[value]   
start   0
```

Here is the datatable initialization javascript code,

```
$(selector).dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": url,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "aoColumnDefs":[
                {
                    'aTargets': 0,
                    'bSortable': true
                },
                {
                    'aTargets': 1,
                    'bSortable': true,
                    'mRender': function (link) {
                        return '<a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    'aTargets': 2,
                    'bSortable': true,
                    'mRender': function (link) {
                        return '<a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
                    }
                }
            ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$(selector).dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": url,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "aoColumnDefs":[{
        'aTargets': 0,
        'bSortable': true
    }, {
        'aTargets': 1,
        'bSortable': true,
        'mRender': function (link) {
            return '<a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
        }
    }, {
        'aTargets': 2,
        'bSortable': true,
        'mRender': function (link) {
            return '<a href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a>';
        }
    }],
    fnServerParams: function(query_strings) {
        query_string.splice(0);

        /*
          query_strings is an Array of Objects like this
            [{name: 'query_string1', value: 'query_string1_value'},
             {name: 'query_string2', value: 'query_string2_value'},
             {name: 'query_string3', value: 'query_string3_value'}]

          As you can see, the 'name' and 'value' represents the query string's key/value pair.
          If you want to add another one you need to add another object:

          query_string.push({
            name: 'page',
            // To get the page number you are going to
            value: $(selector).dataTable().api().page.info().page
          });

        */

    }
});
```